# Set global settings configuration instead of use ANY function on ClickHouse

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

[Based on the documentation](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/any/), ClickHouse (in contrast to MySQL) requires that all expressions in the SELECT, HAVING, and ORDER BY clauses be calculated from keys or from aggregate functions.

Sometimes we just need to let on field out of group, but still group others. I am aware about the pros and crons of that.

I am aware that to get behavior like in MySQL, you can put the other columns in the any aggregate function.

I tried to find on SETTINGS like **sql_mode** (MySql) to change this behavior. I know that we can use the function **any**, but it will be easier to let this setup active by default.

[image]

Comment: Why is it so hard to use the `ANY()` aggregation function? It makes your code more clear to people who have to maintain it later. Allowing un-strict results from grouping queries can cause difficult debugging situations. I recommend you allow the default `sql_mode` to enforce standard semantics. ClickHouse is behaving correctly.

Comment: My app build CH sql on background to the user while this user drag fields/computed columns. Sometimes when we have to decide what to group/order base on what user want build, it is not so easy!

Comment: My apologies. I forgot that MySQL does not have an `ANY()` function (see [Aggregate Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)). Still, you should not allow users to create queries that will have ambiguous results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such setting in CH. And no plans to implement such non-SQL behavior.

Comment: Are you answering about ClickHouse? Because I understood the question to be asking how to relax the behavior in MySQL, and it is possible to do that. Though I recommend keeping the standard behavior.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes I answered about CH. The only way is to use ANY function explicitly